# How to store string received with Serial.read() in Arduino?

Tags: string, arduino

I manage to send data from NodeJs runtime with serialport library.

The goal is storing a string received from `Serial.read()` in Arduino . What is correct:

```
int string = Serial.read()
```

or:

```
char string[20] = Serial.read()
```

There are many documentations on Internet and they are not the same

**P/s**: I send string from nodejs in buffer form but i dont think it matters because arduino still implement it as a string anyway.

Comment: Read [the docs](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/) and call a method that is supposed to return a string and not a char? Or check any of the numerous existing tutorials on serial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Arduino documentation:

```
int incomingByte = 0;   // for incoming serial data
void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

        // send data only when you receive data:
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                incomingByte = Serial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
        }
}
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

.read():

> Returns the first byte of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no
>   data is available) - int

FYI: I've used this code many times and it works on 100%.

Comment: I send a string like "255,255" .Is that now incomingByte is a string with value "255,255" when i use it ? Because first we declare it as int ,not string

Comment: If that's your case, you can use `Serial.readString()` :

`String a;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps

}

void loop() {

while(Serial.available()) {

a= Serial.readString();// read the incoming data as string

Serial.println(a);

}

}`

Comment: OK , thanks,now i understand . but what is the difference between string and char a[] in arduino , because when i try {int number = a[0]} to take the first integer inside the string , it doesnt become 2

Comment: If you need to get a value, specifying the string index, you can use `charAt(n)`. You can find more information about it here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/charat/